# C# code to connect to different domain using windows authentication – SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

We normally use admin access( different domain using windows authentication)
 to retrieve the data from the database by using the below connection which is very time consuming as it is a manual process.

```
 %windir%\system32\runas.exe /netonly /user:domain\username "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"
```

Is there any way where we can programmatically connect to the database using windows authentication on different domain which will save lot of our efforts.

Comment: What research have you tried?  Any code to show?  This will help us help  you.  Good luck!

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? You can impersonate as another user from code that executes SQL no problem.

Comment: see www.connectionstrings.com.  If you are in a different domain you need group access to second domain in the windows user profile.  Have a admin set up a windows user group account and add users to the group.  Then give the SQL database credentials to use the new group account.  The group account in windows will have access to computers in both domains.

Comment: I do have admin access and I have tried below code but still no luck